# Conflict between Antitypical Result and Alamofire Result

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have the following Swift function in a protocol that represents a POST HTTP request:

```
func post<T: Mappable>(url: NSURL, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, completion: ((Result<T, APIClientError>) -> ())?)
```

In this case, I'm doing `import Result` to get Result from Antitypical, because I don't want this protocol to depend on Alamofire.

In an implementation of this protocol, I want to use Alamofire to do the actual HTTP request:

```
func post<T: Mappable>(url: NSURL, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, completion: (Result<T, APIClientError> -> ())? = nil) {
    Alamofire.request(.POST, url.URLString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .validate()
```

The problem is that there is a conflict between Antitypical's Result and Alamofire's Result:

```
AlamofireHTTPClient.swift:21:87: 'Result' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
```

How can I specify that I want to use Result from Antitypical? Or if you know a better way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the exact type you are referring to by `moduleName.Type`; In your case that would be `Result.Result` or `Alamofire.Result` .

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

In Swift 5, you can specify the Swift result type as:

```
Swift.Result<T, APIClientError>
```

Alamofire can be done as:

```
Alamofire.Result<Data>
```